# Can I change the button background color when the mouse is over the button?

Tags: c++, button, wxwidgets, background-color

I created a simple frame with a single `wxbutton`, will I be able to change the button background color when the mouse is over the button?

```
var name = Button1
class name = wxButton
```

If it's so can anyone explain to me how to do it step by step?

Comment: Depends on the speed of the GUI handler.  Check out the paint and redraw methods.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to catch wxEVT_LEAVE_WINDOW  and the wxEVT_ENTER_WINDOW from the Button (not your window) and change the Buttons Background colour within the called function?